# How to stop a list from overflowing from its bullet point in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have created a list with custom-sized bullet points using the below code. I am trying to figure out how to keep the text in line with the bullet points when the screen size changes.

[For example when this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b36Om.png)

How can I get the words threatened and uncommon to stay in line when they have to move to a new line?

```css
ul {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
    li {
        list-style-type:none;
    }
        li:before{
            content: '\00b7'; 
            font-size: 800%; 
            line-height: 14%; 
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>Not Threatened</span></li> 
    <li><span>Naturally Uncommon</span></li>
    <li><span>Relicit</span></li>
    <li><span>Recovering</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To style list bullets, use `::marker`, not `::before`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Comment: Also, part of the problem is caused by your use of `font-size: 800%` combined with `line-height: 14%` (which might break your design if the user has non-default system font-sizes) - is there a reason you can't use inline `data:` with an SVG image for custom bullets instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```css
ul {
  /* using CSS grid to use grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* setting a gap of 0.25em between adjacent
     elements, for both rows and columns: */
  gap: 0.25em;
  /* defining two columns, one of min-content
     occupied by the ::before pseudo element;
     and the other taking 1 fraction of the
     remaining space: */
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

li {
  /* effectively 'removing' the <li> box from
     the layout calculation, to allow us to
     style the contents and have them placed
     into the grid layout of the <ul>: */
  display: contents;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  content: '\00b7';
  font-size: 800%;
  line-height: 14%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit distinctio neque odio eum dolore quas quaerat quisquam, rerum facilis voluptatibus.</span></li>
  <li><span>Naturally Uncommon</span></li>
  <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, ut tempore sapiente eum itaque animi inventore provident delectus asperiores harum quae quibusdam est, ipsam, quod consequuntur, molestiae autem minima. Saepe repellendus mollitia, ipsa quod, modi totam ad nobis vitae maxime.</span></li>
  <li><span>Recovering</span></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tvcxbkrL/).

References:

- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)," CSS-Tricks.
- "[Basic concepts of grid layout]," Mozilla Developer Network.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use `list-style-position: outside`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Long<br>Sentence</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean libero urna, pharetra eget mi quis, volutpat fringilla lectus. Mauris lobortis elit vel fringilla ornare. Nulla fringilla eros vitae convallis malesuada. Donec ornare vulputate condimentum. Pellentesque magna arcu, tempus vitae malesuada vitae, efficitur sit amet nisi. Donec sed facilisis turpis, id elementum erat. Sed dapibus enim ex, ac bibendum mauris eleifend fringilla. Proin commodo nunc quis massa mollis bibendum. Sed commodo erat ac lorem tempor, sed condimentum metus volutpat. Donec venenatis quam arcu. Nullam euismod, odio at blandit dignissim, sapien velit tincidunt enim, eget dapibus dui dui quis purus. Cras pharetra magna nec nulla tincidunt tristique. Sed consequat nisl ullamcorper orci bibendum, eget suscipit erat eleifend.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not a proper solution

Comment: @nagendranag how so? it solves the issue from the image (missing indent caused by a line break). It's easier then to hack the bullet point and trying to replace it afterwards.

Comment: wrapping to newline and indentation should happen without line breaks

Comment: @nagendranag I've added a Lorem Ipsum paragraph, which I think demonstrates the point.

Answer (score -2):

Use in li white space nowrap
`li { list-style: none; white-space:nowrap; }`

Comment: All this does is disable wrapping - rather than _control_ how wrapping does happen.

Comment: It works and solves his problem

Comment: Disabling wrapping _does not_ solve the OP's problem, to see why, try it with the Lorem Ipsum example in @tacoshy's answer

Comment: by causing a different problem: overflow. the wrapping is an intended feature to prevent an overflow. Use a [repro] and use a long text like the lorem ipsum paragraph and you see that your "solution" is not a solution just pushes the issue to another issue.